# Adding a DAO Property to a database

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao

I am trying to create a property through the following code:

```
Public Sub refresh()
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
    Set prp = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("LastRefreshedDate", dbDate, Date)
End Sub
```

I have created the following during my build process to store the LastRefreshedDate and then present this on a user form via a caption label, however, the property is not being displayed.

```
' Store refresh date
CurrentDb.Properties("LastRefreshedDate") = Date
lblRefresh.Caption = "Last Refreshed: " & Format(CurrentDb.Properties("LastRefreshedDate"), " dd mmm yyyy")
```

Comment: What is "not working"?

Comment: the property i am trying to create is not being created, not sure why.

Comment: i was missing db.Properties.Append prp

Comment: Please provide your solution as an answer so that you can accept to be clear for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

"I forgot to append the property to the `CurrentDb`."

Correct code:

```
Public Sub refresh()
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
    Set prp = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("LastRefreshedDate", dbDate, Date)
    ' property has to be appended after it is created.
    Currentdb.Properties.Append prp
End Sub
```

[MSDN documentation on the DAO.Properties collection.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834455%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: **Disclaimer:** OP updated his question with his answer instead of an answer. I have posted it here for him. I added the reference.